# I have a plot that generate from rstudio i want the graph of derivatives (first order) of the graph can i do this in r

Tags: r, plot

the graph looks like this

[image: 1]

code for graph is this (level is a dataframe with 5000 obs)

```
smth<-smooth.spline(level$ohm) 
plot(smth,type="l")
text(x = c(2655,2690,2760,2795,2835,2900,2949,2989,3109,3168,3248), y = c(1030,1020,1010,1000,980,960,940,920,880,850,820), labels = c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"),cex=0.5)
```

is there any function or method that i can output the plot of derivatives of this plot shown above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`diff` does the job:

```
plot(smth$x[-1], diff(smth$y), type="l")
```

You just have to sacrifice the first data point.

Comment: Exactly. I have amended it. Thank you!

Comment: what means sacrifice the first data point

Comment: It basically means that in passing from the primary series to the derivative (i.e. difference) series you lose one data point. If you have `n` data points in the primary series you will have `n-1` points in the difference series. `1:10` has 10 elements but `diff(1:10)` has 9 elements.